# ¿Como hago una inserción en dos tablas Mysql?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Quisiera hacer una inserción a dos tablas diferentes, estuve investigando y algunos ejemplos me indican que es así, pero no me registra en ninguna, no se que este mal, o si haya alguna otra forma de hacerlo, necesito de su ayuda, muchas gracias....

```
public function registro($no_revista, $colaboradores, $fecha_publicacion, $imagen, $archivo, $articulo, $autor){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO revista (no_revista, colaboradores, fecha_publicacion, articulo_1, autor_1, imagen, archivo) 
        VALUES ('$no_revista', '$colaboradores', '$fecha_publicacion', '$imagen', '$archivo')";
        $consulta = $this->conecta()->query($sql);

        $sql1 = "INSERT INTO articulos (articulo, autor) 
        VALUES ('$articulo', '$autor')";
        $consulta = $this->conecta()->query($sql);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu primera consulta, ingresas más parametros de los que ingresas.

```
INSERT INTO revista (no_revista, colaboradores, fecha_publicacion, articulo_1, autor_1, imagen, archivo)
```

y no utilizas articulo_1 ni autor_1, entonces en la consulta cuando ingresas los valores:

```
    VALUES ('$no_revista', '$colaboradores', '$fecha_publicacion', '$imagen', '$archivo')
```

solucion:

```
 public function registro($no_revista, $colaboradores, $fecha_publicacion, $imagen, $archivo, $articulo, $autor){

    $sql = "INSERT INTO revista (no_revista, colaboradores, fecha_publicacion, imagen, archivo) 

    VALUES ('$no_revista', '$colaboradores', '$fecha_publicacion', '$imagen', '$archivo')";

    $consulta = $this->conecta()->query($sql);
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO articulos (articulo, autor) 
    VALUES ('$articulo', '$autor')";
    $consulta = $this->conecta()->query($sql1);
```

}

guardaria en tu tablarevista en la columan de articulo_1 guarda lo que coniene tu variable $imagen y en la columna de autor_1 gurda lo que contiene tu variable $archivo, pero como no ingresaste ni l aimagen ni el archivo con parametros no los toma en cuenta. 
La primera solucion es quitando esos parametros:

y en la segunda consulta

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono de maravilla, aprovechando, si quisiera eliminar o editar en ambas tablas se hace la misma logística?

Comment: Hola @R.Vivi para realizar un delete masivo hay que hacer una consulta multiple, un ejemplo sería algo así `"UPDATE perfiles, contactos, inscripciones SET perfiles.curp = '$curp', perfiles.nombres = '$nombres', perfiles.appaterno = '$appaterno', perfiles.apmaterno = '$apmaterno', contactos.calleynum ='$direccion', inscripciones.fechapago = '$fechapago' WHERE perfiles.idperfil = contactos.idperfil AND contactos.idperfil = inscripciones.idperfil AND inscripciones.idperfil = '$idperfil';"` sin embargo, para poder ayudarte, te invito a hacer una nueva pregunta con tu nuevo problema.

Comment: Perfecto, ahora genero la pregunta y muchas muchas gracias por su atención, saludos!...